# Linux: How to create a zip from the result of a grep

Tags: linux, grep, zip

I have a directory that has over 6 million files.
I can't list them all and I need to zip a few of them.

Can I do something like:

```
$zip -r archive.zip dir1/ | grep "*_201605*"
```

so far everytime I run this command it zips everything.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example in manual:

```
zip -R foo "*.c"
```

You could adapt for your case:

```
zip -r archive.zip "dir1/*_201605*"
```

For more complicated cases you can profit from the `--names-stdin` option which is:

> Take the list of input files from standard input. Only one filename per line.